# View data with Stored Procedure using parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

got a little problem when displaying my views using stored procedure with parameters.

Here is my code:

**View**

```html
@model IEnumerable<PEMCOLoan.DAL.Entities.spModels.getLoanWithTypes>

@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "List of Summary per Loan Types";
}

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Educational Loan</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Petty Cash</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Business Loan</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>Educational Loan</h3>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Employee ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Loan Type</th>
                <th>Principal</th>
                <th>Interest</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeID)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LoanTypeID)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PrincipalAmount)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Interest)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)</td>
                </tr>

            }
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Petty Cash</h3>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Employee ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Loan Type</th>
                <th>Principal</th>
                <th>Interest</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeID)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LoanTypeID)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PrincipalAmount)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Interest)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)</td>
                </tr>

            }
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Business Loan</h3>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Employee ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Loan Type</th>
                <th>Principal</th>
                <th>Interest</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeID)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LoanTypeID)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PrincipalAmount)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Interest)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)</td>
                </tr>

            }
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want in my view is I want to check what type of loan is it suppose to get along with the table. For example if I if there is loan type 1,2,3, if loan type 1 will go along with the records with `Educational Loan`, 2 will go with petty cash and so on... here are the pictures that I worked on. [image: Educational Loan] Which is hows the same on the rest of the panels.

**Controller**

*Right now I had this temporarily*

```
        [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_Context.Set<getLoanWithTypes>().FromSql("sp_GetLoanTypesWithPrincipal").AsNoTracking());
    }
```

*Here is my partial code with parameters*

```
        [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index(getLoanWithTypes glwt)
    {



        return View(_Context.Set<getLoanWithTypes>().FromSql("sp_GetLoanTypesWithPrincipal @p0 = {0}, @p1 = {1}", glwt.EmployeeID.ToString(), glwt.LoanTypeID.ToString()).AsNoTracking());
    }
```

I have a little problem with it cuz I don't know how to pass parameters from the view.  What I want to do with it is I want to set the parameter for each `LoanTypeID` when the view loads. Or simply clicking each panel and it sets the `LoanTypeID` parameter.

**SQL:**
*Parameters:*
    @empID AS INT = NULL,
    @loanID AS INT = NULL

*Query:*

```
SELECT
[EmployeeID] = emp.EmployeeID,
[FullName] = emp.FName + ' ' + emp.LName,
[LoanTypeID] = lt.LoanTypeID,
[PrincipalAmount] = (SELECT ISNULL(SUM((CAST(((lc.LoanAmount) / ((dbo.fnNumberOfYears(CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), LoanDateStart, 101), CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), LoanPaymentDue, 101)) * 12)  * 2)) AS DECIMAL(18,2)))),0) FROM LoanContract lc INNER JOIN LoanType lt ON lt.LoanTypeID = lc.LoanTypeID WHERE lc.LoanTypeID = @loanID AND lc.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID),
[Interest] = (SELECT ISNULL(SUM((CAST((((lt.InterestRate/100) * lc.LoanAmount) / ((dbo.fnNumberOfYears(CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), LoanDateStart, 101), CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), LoanPaymentDue, 101)) * 12)  * 2)) AS DECIMAL(18,2)))),0) FROM LoanContract lc INNER JOIN LoanType lt ON lt.LoanTypeID = lc.LoanTypeID WHERE lc.LoanTypeID = @loanID AND lc.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID),
[Total] = (SELECT ISNULL(SUM((CAST(((((lt.InterestRate/100) * lc.LoanAmount) + lc.LoanAmount) / ((dbo.fnNumberOfYears(CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), LoanDateStart, 101), CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), LoanPaymentDue, 101)) * 12)  * 2)) AS DECIMAL(18,2)))),0) FROM LoanContract lc INNER JOIN LoanType lt ON lt.LoanTypeID = lc.LoanTypeID WHERE lc.LoanTypeID = @loanID AND lc.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID)
FROM Employee emp
    INNER JOIN Salary sal ON sal.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN LoanContract lc ON lc.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN LoanType lt ON lt.LoanTypeID = lc.LoanTypeID
    LEFT JOIN LoanPayments lp ON lp.LoanID = lc.LoanID
    LEFT JOIN LoanFrequency lf ON lf.LoanFrequencyID = lc.LoanFrequencyID
WHERE emp.EmployeeID IN (SELECT EmployeeID FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeID LIKE '%' + CASE WHEN ISNULL(@empID,0) <> 0 THEN CAST(ISNULL(@empID, 0) AS VARCHAR(15)) ELSE '' END + '%')
    AND lc.LoanTypeID IN (SELECT LoanTypeID FROM LoanType WHERE LoanTypeID LIKE '%' + CASE WHEN ISNULL(@loanID,0) <> 0 THEN CAST(ISNULL(@loanID, 0) AS VARCHAR(15)) ELSE '' END + '%')
GROUP BY emp.EmployeeID, lt.LoanTypeID, emp.FName, emp.LName
ORDER BY emp.EmployeeID ASC
```

What it does is that it for each employee it will get their current `PrincipalAmount`, `Interest` and so on... if `PrincipalAmount` have the same LoanTypeID and EmployeeID then it will compute and sum. Here is the sample picture [image: Query Sample Picture]

I'm a bit new to asp.net core and ef core as well with no advance knowledge yet.

Hopefully this suffice everything.  Any good reference to read or suggestion will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> You can construct a `DbParameter` and supply it as a parameter value.
>   This allows you to use named parameters in the SQL query string

```
var employeeId = new SqlParameter("empID", glwt.EmployeeID);
var loanTypeId = new SqlParameter("loanID", glwt.LoanTypeID);
var data = _Context
               .Set<getLoanWithTypes>()
               .FromSql("EXECUTE sp_GetLoanTypesWithPrincipal @empID, @loanID", employeeId, loanTypeId)
               .AsNoTracking();
return View(data);
```

The framework will match the parameters up to the command.

Reference - [Raw SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#passing-parameters)